# Using res.download()

Tags: node.js

I have a route that goes like this:

```
exports.downloadFile = app => {
    app.get('/install/download', (request, result) => {
        result.download(`${__dirname}../../../public/exec/install.exe`, error => {
            if (error) console.log("[FAILURE][RESOURCE] Could not download installation file\r\n");
            else console.log("[SUCCESS][RESOURCE] Installation file has been downloaded\r\n");
        });
    });
}
```

With this route, I am trying to make it that when I click on a button this file is downloaded. When I click the button I get a message indicating SUCCESS, but my browser makes no indication of any download and does not prompt me to do anything. Is there some additional component I need to add to make sure it works?

This is the code on my client side to do the fetching:

```
const downloadFile = () => {
    const url = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/install/download`;
    fetch(url)
        .catch(error => alertMessage(error.message));
}
```

I am assuming it might have to do with me having no `.then` to handle the fetch, but I am not sure what I should be adding there and I am under the impression from the documentation that the browser automatically handles this part?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to pass one download name argument.
Please modify download function as below.

```
result.download(`${__dirname}../../../public/exec/install.exe`, 'install.exe', error => {
            if (error) console.log("[FAILURE][RESOURCE] Could not download installation file\r\n");
            else console.log("[SUCCESS][RESOURCE] Installation file has been downloaded\r\n");
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't thought to mention I had tried that as I believe it is an optional parameter. I had already tried that and it has the exact same result, and I tried it again just to be sure then.

Comment: Please check file path. just to check put install.exe to the root path.

Comment: Yeah I have triple-checked the path. Tried it in the folder designated as static as well in case it needed to be there. Each time it tells me I am successful until I deliberately give a wrong file path and then it tells me I am not successful.