# Download link through HTTP server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to create a download link for my website as follows:

```
<a href="../../exec/install.exe" download="install.exe" target="_blank"></a>
```

This approach works perfectly when running the website locally from my computer, but when I run it on a server I get the error "Failed - No file" on Chrome, and nothing happening on Firefox. I am attempting this approach after I tried achieving the same thing through an [Express route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878190/using-res-download), but running into blocks with that too.

I believe the problem has to do with the server moving files to different locations in the "virtual file directory" when running, and so href needs to point somewhere else, but I can't find any examples of where to point it. It seems the most common problem is cross-origins policy, but I have no trouble with that.

Short excerpt of directory structure as follows:

```
-> exec
    -> install.exe (file to download)
-> public
    -> pages
        -> index.html (file with download link)
-> server.js (file that serves index.html at "/home")
```

Comment: have you tired by giving absolute URL in href

Comment: I wouldn't be sure what absolute URL to provide. From my current understanding if I set `href="localhost:3000/exec/install.exe"` (the folder exec is located in my root directory) then the link will attempt to find a route located at `/exec`? I have tried typing that absolute URL in but it has the same error.

Comment: I have added a short description of my file directory structure to the original question if that helps?

Comment: does exec folder is publicly accessible? using url if not then you need to. [Follow this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I have tried again placing the file in the folders accessible through express.static, however I am still having trouble with getting it work (I am not too sure what would be correct to enter for `href`).

Answer (score 0):

Going off your directory structure, it looks like anything outside of your `public` directory is not publicly-accessible - that is, the server can see it and knows it's there but does not allow the browser to access it.

Try moving the exe into the public folder and changing your `href`.

I'm willing to bet the reason it works locally is because your entire filesystem is readable by the browser, so it will happily go up 2 levels, whereas the server doesn't allow the same behaviour

Comment: I had tried it a little bit yesterday but after your comment I tried putting it back into the section that is accessible with `express.static`, however it produces the same error (and still works locally from my computer). I think my trouble is figuring out what exactly to enter for `href`?